# How to call method in fixed time interval (without threads)

Tags: java

I have to handle animation of some objects. For now I have done it with 4 methods: `getAnimationCooldown()`, `resetAnimationCooldown()`, `subAnimationCooldown()` and `nextFrame()`.

But for sure there is easier way to do this. I'd like to call method `nextFrame()` every 100ms. Is there an easy way to do this? I know `ScheduledExecutor` and `Timer` but I see they create new threads for this task and I need to call this method in `for()` loop for every object in this loop. So is there some easy way to just call it like:

```
for (Object object : objects) {
 every(100, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS) {
  object.nextFrame();
 }
}
```

Comment: How about creating one single timer, which will iterate over all objects every 100 ms?

Comment: It should be done in this loop because it animates only objects which implment Animatable interface. Of course I could do second thread but it would be waste of power to interate over all objects second time I think..

Comment: Wouldn't calling `Thread.sleep(200)` in this loop be enough?

Comment: Nope because there is also handling moving, shooting ans do on.. :/ It looks creating second thread will be needed..

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas are:

First: Is it possible to invert the requirement to call nextFrame every 100ms?  If so, it could become "Call nextFrame as often as you can, & the object will update **appropriately for the amount of time** since its last nextFrame"?  You'd still want to call it often enough, but this would remove the pressure to call nextFrame at precise 100ms intervals.

With this idea, your main loop would deal with each of the actions you mention, like this:

```
while(!isGameOver()) {
  moving();
  shooting();
  for (Object object : objects) {
    object.nextFrame();
  }
}
```

Second: Switch to a fully **event-driven model**, but beware the "inside out logic" danger of that model.